# How do you do a recursive hierarchical calculation in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I need to dynamically calculate the total number of descendants in an editable tree/hierarchy. I know how to watch items but not items of items.

### For example:

```
Item 1 | Number of Descendants: 5
  Item 1:1 | Number of Descendants: 3
    Item 1:1:1 | Number of Descendants: 0
    Item 1:1:2 | Number of Descendants: 0
    Item 1:1:3 | Number of Descendants: 0
  Item 1:2 | Number of Descendants: 0
```

Do I have to put a watch on all the levels?

### What I have so far:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('exampleCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.item = {
    'name': 'Item 1',
    'numberOfDescendants': 5,
    'items': [{
      'name': 'Item 1:1',
      'numberOfDescendants': 3,
      'items': [{
        'name': 'Item 1:1:1',
        'numberOfDescendants': 0,
      }, {
        'name': 'Item 1:1:2',
        'numberOfDescendants': 0,
      }, {
        'name': 'Item 1:1:3',
        'numberOfDescendants': 0,
      }, ]
    }, {
      'name': 'Item 1:2',
      'numberOfDescendants': 0,
    }, ]
  };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app' ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="itemView">
    {{item.name}} |
    Number of Descendants: {{item.numberOfDescendants}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in item.items" ng-include="'itemView'"></li>
    </ul>
  </script>
  
  <div ng-include="'itemView'"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: will have to loop through all levels recursively

Comment: the angular framework doesn't provide any tools to do this task, you'll probably need to evaluate your data in JavaScript.

Comment: How do I hook into the digest cycle to do the calculation? It wold be bad to put a watch on every item.